# How to separate one string into 2 strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, trim

I am using C#.NET and Windows CE Compact Framework. I have a code where in it should separate one string into two textboxes.

```
textbox1 = ID
textbox2 = quantity

string BarcodeValue= "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";

textbox1.text = BarcodeValue.Remove(0, BarcodeValue.Length - BarcodeValue.IndexOf(' ') + 2);
//Output: JN061704Z00

textbox2.text = BarcodeValue.Remove(10, 0).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');
//Output: should be 1090 but I am getting a wrong output: 10901321 JN061704Z00
//Please take note that 1090 can be any number, can be 999990 or  90 or 1
```

Can somebody help me with this? :((

THANKS!!

Comment: what is the "wrong output" you are getting; also, I doubt you are getting JN061704X00 - because the input has no X

Comment: @MarcGravell that should be Z instead of X, already edit it. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `Split()`

```
string BarcodeValue= "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";
string[] tmp = BarcodeValue.Split(' ');
textbox1.text = tmp[1];
textbox2.text= tmp[0].SubString(0,tmp[0].Length-4).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: output: 10901321, I just need 1090

Comment: can your describe algorithm of getting quantity?

Comment: is it always last 4 digits of first part of string that you don't need?

Comment: Yes. the last 4 digits i need to remove

Comment: but 1090 can be any number 999999999 or 9

Comment: try `textbox2.text= tmp[0].Remove(tmp[0].Length-4,tmp[0].Length).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');`

Comment: or `textbox2.text= tmp[0].Substring(0,tmp[0].Length-4).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');`

Comment: Thank you @Guru Stron.. Got the right output.. thanks thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `Split` method:

```
string BarcodeValue = "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";
var splitted = BarcodeValue.Split(' '); //splits string by space    

textbox1.text = splitted[1];

textbox2.text = splitted[0].Remove(10).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');
```

you probably should check if splitted length is 2 before accessing it to avoid `IndexOutOfBound` exception.

Comment: I edited my answer, to remove anything after 10 characters, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did. But I am getting an error of No overload for method Remove. I forgot to mention a while ago that I am using a Windows Ce Compact Framework

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string BarcodeValue = "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";

        var text1 = BarcodeValue.Split(' ')[1];
        var text2 = BarcodeValue.Split(' ')[0].Remove(10).Trim('+');

        Console.WriteLine(text1);
        Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(text2));
    }
```

Result:

```
JN061704Z00
1090
```

Comment: I tried Remove(10) but I am getting No overload for method Remove maybe because I am using Compact Framework for Windows CE

Answer (score 1):

The `Remove(10,0)` removes zero characters. You want `Remove(10)` to remove everything after position 10.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Remove.aspx) for the two versions.

Alternatively, use `Substring(0,10)` to get the first 10 characters.

Comment: I tried Remove(10) but I am getting No overload for method Remove.

Comment: @QKWS - that's strange, that overload was added in [version 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

a slightly better version of the code posted above.

```
          string BarcodeValue= "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";
           if(BarcodeValue.Contains(' '))
           {
              var splitted = BarcodeValue.Split(' ');

              textbox1.text = splitted[1];

              textbox2.text = splitted[0].TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string BarcodeValue = "+0000010901321 JN061704Z00";

var splittedString = BarcodeValue.Split(' ');   

TextBox1.Text = splittedString [0].Remove(10).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0'); 

TextBox2.Text = splittedString [1];
```

**Output**-

```
TextBox1.Text = 1090

TextBox2.Text = JN061704Z00
```

Answer (score 0):

This works only if the barcodeValue length is always const.

```
    string[] s1 = BarcodeValue.Split(' ');
    textBox1.Text = s1[0];
    textBox2.Text = s1[1];

    string _s = s1[0].Remove(0, 6).Remove(3, 4);
    textBox3.Text = _s;
```